# Need help identifying some cable connectors and their use case

Tags: connection, cable, connector

- First up

  - I can't identify the connector on the left. The middle one is USB mini B and the right is USB micro B
  - I don't think it's any USB or HDMI connector
  - The other end is a regular USB Type A
  - [image: photo 1]
- Second up

  - One end is a female parallel port and the other end is split into female VGA and male RJ11 connector
  - [image: photo 2a]
  - [image: photo 2b]
- Third up

  - Just a regular 25 pin parallel port extension?
  - What was it used for?
  - [image: photo 3]
- Fourth up

  - I think this is a 36 pin to 25 pin parallel port adapter?
  - How does it add pins?
  - what was it used for?
  - [image: photo 4]
- Fifth up

  - This absolute monstrosity
  - Appears to be a male 25 pin parallel port that splits to 2 female 25 pin parallel ports and then each of those has a VGA adapter on it
  - Was this used for dual screens?
  - [image: photo 5a]
  - [image: photo 5b]
- Sixth up

  - A male Molex(?) connector to two female VGA connectors
  - Used for dual screens?
  - [image: photo 6]

Comment: Too many questions here, they need to be asked on an individual basis.

Comment: @Moab ah okay, will do that, should I delete this question?

Comment: I would not delete (rep hit) better to get it closed by our Votes,  Post 6 separate questions anytime you wish.

Comment: "Guess the connector" questions are [borderline off-topic](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7647/are-hardware-port-cable-etc-visual-identification-questions-allowed-or-not) as they cannot easily be searched. While you have a very definite image they are still technically "guess the thing" and I'm on the fence for closing this.

Comment: @Mokubai yea that's fair enough. Do you have any suggestions for where might be more appropriate? I've asked on /r/cableadvice but it's not a very active community.

Comment: Honestly? I'd look through https://pinouts.ru/. This isn't really a [hardwarerecs.se] question and I don't think we have any other sites. That said the meta question I linked doesn't really give a definitive "this is acceptable" or "this is not acceptable" answer which is why I'm not outright closing this.

Comment: Rather that getting this one deleted, edit it to one of the six you need identified. Then you don't get the rep hit and you get answers. It's a good question it just needs a little tweaking to fit better into the weird way we do things here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 is [Micro-USB](https://Micro-USB%20B) B, or [Mini-USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Mini_connectors) B. See *[USB Connector Guides](https://www.cablestogo.com/learning/connector-guides/usb)*

2: I have a feeling it might have been for a 'fax printer' combined type unit. So the [RJ11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#RJ11,_RJ14,_RJ25_wiring) would go to a phone line, giving a printer (with serial connectivity if it needed a modem) phone capability.

3 - yes, extension cord, for things that are far away ;)

4 - the added pins are likely ground pins, so they can all terminate to the same point.

5 - That's not [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array); it's 9-pin [D-sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature#Communications_ports). It looks like it may of been for connecting to a printer, or some other kind of embedded device, but this is always going to be guess work.

6 - As answered in chat by Journey Man Geek, that is [DMS-59](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59). So yes, two monitors to a single port on a graphics card.

This is also a great resource for identifying ports: *[Computer Ports – Name and Location Of Connections On Computer](https://removeandreplace.com/2013/04/13/computer-ports-learn-the-name-and-location-of-the-connections-on-your-desktop-computer-or-laptop/)*

Comment: Thanks very much. Only mistake I think is number 1. As Austin said it's probably a proprietary USB connection because it definitely isn't any type of regular USB. The port identifying link is a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. Is probably a proprietary USB connection, most likely for some early mobile phone or a digital camera.  Before [Micro-USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Micro_connectors) became commonplace, a lot of companies that made USB-connected peripherals used custom connectors on the device side, either so they could reuse the same connector for multiple purposes, or just to force users to buy cables through them.  I think I've seen that shape and size before, but I don't remember where.
2. I am not sure. I'd have to see how exactly it's wired.  It might be a combined fax/printer unit as mentioned in another answer, it might be some kind of [RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) splitter cable (that's a [DE-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature#Communications_ports) connector, not a VGA connector BTW), or it may be some completely custom cable.
3. Is probably a straight-through extender cable.  In theory, usable for any application requiring a longer cable with [DB-25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature#Communications_ports) connectors (not necessarily parallel, old RS-232 serial links, especially for terminal servers, would also use DB-25, albeit with reverse gender on the connectors relative to parallel connectors).  However, there isn't any way to be certain without checking the wiring (if it's short, it might be a special adapter cable, like a null modem cable).
4. Is an [IEEE 1284](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1284) parallel cable, with a DB-25 connector at one end, and a 36-pin micro ribbon connector (sometimes called a 'Centronics' connector after the company that developed the original version of the IEEE standard) on the other end. The different connectors were used for the same reason that USB conventionally used separate connectors for the host and the device. These were the norm for parallel printers for many years. I don't recall how the extra pins were connected (probably either grounded or left floating). A 50-pin version of the same micro-ribbon connector was used for both the original [SCSI-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI) standard, as well as for [RJ21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#RJ11,_RJ14,_RJ25_wiring) connections in analog telephone systems (carrying 25 phone lines in one cable, mostly used at branch exchanges).
5. Is probably an RS-232 splitter.  The old DB-25 RS-232 connectors mentioned above could be wired to have two serial links over the same connector, and such a cable would be needed to connect two devices with DE-9 connectors to such a port.
6. Is a proprietary video-card adapter cable.  Some older small-form-factor video cards use the crazy looking connector (it's not Molex, but I'm not sure what the branding is) with all the pins as their only external connector, and then require an adapter like that to split out to individual video connections.  I've never seen one that splits to two VGA connections myself, but I've seen ones that split to two [DVI-I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Connector) or a DVI-I and a VGA before.